# Printing most frequent elements in a sorted queue by recently added order

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, queue

ListTopVisitedSites(sites, 5) is supposed to return the following output:

```
www.google.com | 4  
www.aol.com | 3  
www.microsoft.com | 3  
www.amazon.com | 3  
www.facebook.com | 3
```

I am trying to print the top 5 elements. If multiple elements have the same quantity, they should be ordered by recency - (recently added). Also, I need to print an empty array of type string for no value.

Which part am I missing, or have coded incorrectly? All the methods and their parameters should remain the same, as I am supposed to keep the time complexity as N<sup>2</sup> and space complexity as 1.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
class SiteStats {

    private String url;
    private int numVisits;


    public SiteStats(String url, int numVisits) {
        this.url = url;
        this.numVisits = numVisits;
    }


    public int getNumVisits() {
        return this.numVisits;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public void setNumVisits(int updatedNumVisits) {
        this.numVisits = updatedNumVisits;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.url + " | " + this.numVisits;
    }

}

public class PartBSolution {

    private static Queue<SiteStats> sites = new LinkedList<SiteStats>();



    public static void listTopVisitedSites(Queue<SiteStats> sites, int n) {

        sortQueue(sites);

        while(sites.isEmpty()== false)
        {
            System.out.println(sites.peek() + " ");
            sites.poll();
        }

    }
    public static void insertMaxToRear(Queue<SiteStats> sites,
                                       int max_index)
    {
        SiteStats max_value = null;
        int s = sites.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            SiteStats current = sites.peek();
            sites.poll();
            if (i != max_index)
                sites.add(current);
            else
                max_value = current;
        }
        sites.add(max_value);
    }

    public static void sortQueue(Queue<SiteStats> sites)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= sites.size(); i++)
        {
            int max_index = maxIndex(sites,sites.size() - i);
            insertMaxToRear(sites, max_index);
        }
    }

    public static int maxIndex(Queue<SiteStats> sites,
                               int sortIndex)
    {
        int max_index = -1;
        int max_value = 0;
        int s = sites.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            SiteStats current = sites.peek();

            sites.poll();
            if (current.getNumVisits() >= max_value && i <= sortIndex)
            {
                max_index = i;
                max_value = current.getNumVisits();
            }
            sites.add(current);
        }
        return max_index;
    }


    public static void updateCount(String url) {
        boolean flag=false;
        int size2=sites.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < size2 ; i++)
        {
            SiteStats temp=sites.peek();
            sites.poll();
            if(temp.getUrl().equals(url))
            {
                temp.setNumVisits(temp.getNumVisits()+1);
                flag=true;
                sites.add(temp);
                break;
            }
            sites.add(temp);
        }
        if(!flag)
            sites.add(new SiteStats(url,1));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] visitedSites = { "www.google.com", "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com", "www.aol.com", "www.google.com", "www.youtube.com",
                "www.facebook.com", "www.aol.com", "www.facebook.com", "www.google.com", "www.microsoft.com", "www.9gag.com", "www.netflix.com",
                "www.netflix.com", "www.9gag.com", "www.microsoft.com", "www.amazon.com", "www.amazon.com", "www.uber.com", "www.amazon.com",
                "www.microsoft.com", "www.aol.com" };

        for (String url : visitedSites) {
            updateCount(url);
        }
        listTopVisitedSites(sites, 5);

    }

}


/**
www.google.com | 4
www.aol.com | 3
www.microsoft.com | 3
www.amazon.com | 3
www.facebook.com | 3
*/
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ?

Comment: It is printing all the elements instead of only 5 I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `n` that you pass into `listTopVisitedSites(sites, 5);` is never used again, so you can not expect it to only list the 5

Comment: I modified it per the suggestion above. However, since the last 4 elements have the same qty of occurrences, The order need to be: Google, Aol,Facebook, Amazon, and Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You did not write the logic for parameter n of listTopVisitedSites. Please find the updated one.

```
   public static void listTopVisitedSites(Queue<SiteStats> sites, int n) {
        sortQueue(sites);
        int iterate = 1;
        while (sites.isEmpty() == false && iterate <= n) {
            System.out.println(sites.peek() + " ");
            sites.poll();
            iterate++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes. This is working. However, the output should return the elements in the following order: Google, AOL, Microsoft, Amazon and Facebook. This is because if there are elements that share the same quantity.  they should be ordered by recency - (recently added). So in this case, Microsoft needs to be listed before Amazon before Facebook.